# How to upload already available folder containing different text (latex) files in TexMaker?

Tags: texmaker

I have the zip file of the latex document. This is a document of thesis. I want to view this document and edit some things using the TexMaker text editor. There is a folder which contains different text files like, Introduction, Motivation, State of the Art etc and ofcourse a main file which includes all these sections into a single fileto execute.

My question is: How can I open the already available document (or folder) in the TexMaker?

[image]

Kindly explain the procedure to upload the folder or zip file.

Comment: TeXmaker isn't an online tool, so there is no upload to do. Did you just try File -> Open?

Comment: If you've installed TeXmaker, you just need to extract the zip file. Then you can double click to files with extension `.tex` to open it in TeXmaker. Alternatively you can start TeXmaker and use `File` → `Open` or key combination `Ctrl` + `O` to open the file selector, where you can select the file, you want to open.